# UseConcMarkSweepGC Erroe while running logstash

Tags: java, logstash

I have tried to run logstash in Windows 10

```
C:\>c:\logstash\bin\logstash.bat -f c:\logstash\config\logs-pipeline.conf
```

And

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2
```

I install jdbc with this [post](https://xiaoxiaosam007.medium.com/logstash-data-output-to-sql-database-52cea0abe3db)

```
bin\logstash-plugin.bat install logstash-output-jdbc
```

And got that error

```
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

logs-pipeline.conf:

```
input{
    rabbitmq {
        host => "127.0.0.1" 
        subscription_retry_interval_seconds => 90
        queue => "TestQueue"
        threads => 2
        passive => true
        codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
jdbc{
driver_jar_path => "C:\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=tdfgdfgest;integratedSecurity=true"
statement => [ "INSERT into DB.TMP.samsamt (w, test1, test2, kkk) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", "client_num", "consignee_name", "@timestamp","host" ]
}
}
```

[logstash.bat](https://justpaste.it/1mw76)   [jvm.options](https://justpaste.it/8j3vx)

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Logstash does not support Java 15.

You need to use one of the [supported versions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html#ls-jvm)

> Logstash requires one of these versions:
>
> Java 8
> Java 11
> Java 14

Comment: Do you talking about jdk or jre ?

Comment: It is the Java version, JDK is the development kit for a Java version and JRE is just the run time for a Java version, but you do not have a JRE for Java Version 15, at least not one from Oracle. You are using JDK for Java Version 15, Logstash does not work with this version, you need to use the bundled Java, as explained in the documentation linked in the answer, or install the JDK for one of the supported versions.

Comment: When I download from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html I got `Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseConcMarkSweepGC; support was removed in 14.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction; support was removed in 14.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly; support was removed in 14.0` good?

Answer (score 2):

Jdk 15 don't support `ConcMarkSweepGC` GC

```
JDK 15 removed support for the CMS-related flags..
```

from jdk description

Your script logstash.bat has link to file jvm.options, and there are next settings:

```
## GC configuration
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

delete these strings and try to run.

Comment: I update my post with `logs-pipeline.conf` ehre do I need to et that configuration? if jdk 15 doesn't support what do I need to do ??

Comment: I add link to logstash.bat because I can't copy to the post so much data, thanks!

Comment: I saw it, this script has string which link to file jvm.options, what you know about this file? Can you show it?

Comment: I add `jvm.options`

Comment: I change my answer, see it please